# Loading page with a single record from a list of records. [PHP]

Tags: php, mysql, sql, hyperlink

I'm a complete beginner using a MySQL database and PHP

I'm looking to load a single record from a page with a list of records by clicking a link.

I've got the list of records working and when the link is clicked it takes the user to the page with this url:

```
/view.php?v=1 (with 1 being the ID of the record I clicked on the menu)
```

How do I load the relevant record (The one with '1' as the ID) on the page? It seems like it would be simple but I can't find how to do it anywhere.

Obviously I would need to use an SQL statement to get the content from the Database but what would I need to put? Something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Topics WHERE TopicID=v";
```

Comment: This should be covered by lots of different introductory tutorials to PHP.  Essentially you would get the value from the query string with `$_GET['v']`, validate that value (since it's user input and can't be implicitly trusted), and use it as a parameter in your SQL query (using something like `mysqli` or `PDO`).

Comment: As @David says, you need to look at the `$_GET` "superglobal" for this data. It may be worth converting your value to an integer, for safety. See [an example here](https://github.com/halfer/php-tutorial-project/blob/rebase4/view-post.php) for how a page retrieves a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `URL's` variable by `$_GET`

```
$topic_id = $_GET['v'];
```

You can pass parameters in query rather that dumping just variable:

```
$query = $PDO->prepare(SELECT * FROM Topics WHERE TopicID=:topic_id);
$query->bindValue(':topic_id', $topic_id);
```

This document will guide you more. http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Comment: Maybe providing SQL-injectable code to a novice developer isn't the best idea?

Comment: I have edited the answer. Thanks for steering me out.

Comment: The second line is a bare query, and would need to be held in a variable, and fed into a database call. Maybe it's worth noting in your answer what is code and what is pseudocode? (Now you have edited, you can just remove the bare query, since it is confusing).

Answer (score -2):

So this would be your PHP script:

```
// Establish your database connection, replace credentials with yours:    
$dbc = new PDO('mysql:host=' . MYSQL_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PW, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));

// Get the id from the URL:
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'v');

// Set up the sql query:
$q = "SELECT * FROM Topics WHERE TopicID = $id";

// Execute the query and get the result:
$result = $dbc->query($q);

// Fetch the only row for your result:
$row = $result->fetch();
```

Now, you can do whatever you want with the record ($row). It's an array, so, for example, if you wanted to get the 'date' column, or whatever you have, it would be $row['date']. I don't know how the Topics table is structured, but whatever columns you have there, then it's just $row[''] and that's where you get the value.

Also note that I didn't put any validation support. So you will have to verify the input on your own. This code is basic and just assumes that the data in the $_GET variable is valid.

/view.php?v=fuckyou would not work and you would get an error.

Comment: `"assumes that the data in the $_GET variable is valid"` - That's called SQL injection.  It's generally best not to write SQL-injectable code.

Comment: This isn't a family-friendly site, but I'm sure the aggressive and abusive query string is unnecessary. Would you amend it?

Answer (score -2):

You can use the bellow code to get a single record values from the table

```
URL :- www.abc.com/view.php?v=1 // Your url    

$id = $_GET['v']; // get these value    

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password"); // connect the database with your credentials     

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Topics` where TopicID = $id limit 1 "); // sql query    

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {    
    echo $row["TopicID"];    
    echo $row["TopicName"];    
}
```

Comment: This code uses a deprecated MySQL library and has a SQL injection vulnerability.